# How to remove the first blank line in tabbing environment?

Tags: boxes, minipage, tabbing

I put some texts enclosed within `tabbing`, embedded in `fbox` and `minipage`:

```
\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}%
\begin{tabbing}
\quad \= \quad \= \quad \= \quad \= \quad \= \hspace{5cm} \= \\[-\baselineskip]\\
 ...
 ...
\end{tabbing}
\end{minipage}}\hfill
```

Though the first blank line `\quad \= \quad \= \quad ...` is used to determine the format, its appearance in the paper  annoys me a little bit... Is there any way to do not show it in the figure?

Comment: Your `\fbox` has a spurious space at its left: write in the way I've edited your message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `\kill` instead of `\\` at the end of the first line. `\kill` causes that this line would not be printed.